# Relationship between Characteristic Function and Eigenfunction

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

In probability we talk about "characteristic functions" of random variables, usually written as $\Phi_X(t)=E[e^{itX}]$. Is the characteristic function in some sense an "eigenfunction" (a function f such that for some operator A, $Af=\lambda f$ for $\lambda \in R$)? If so, is it correct to say that the operator in question is differentiation with respect to $t$, and that the eigenvalues are the moments of $X$? Is the space on which the operator acts the set of all functions of t, or is it more restricted? Also, in probability we always set $t=0$ to recover the moments. How can this be taken into account when thinking in terms of operators?

Comment: No. An eigenfunction of an operator only has one eigenvalue, so your proposal doesn't make sense as it postulates a whole bunch of eigenvalues. You can think of the characteristic function as a kind of generating function instead.

Comment: OK, then assume just one eigenvalue, namely E[X]. Would it work then? Or is this whole thing just a situation where probabilists borrowed a term from a different branch of math and gave it a completely different meaning?

Comment: Completely different objects, no relationship. The same terminology got recycled. The characteristic function is really the Fourier transform of the push-forward measure. It "characterizes" the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The term characteristic function is used in this context more to mean that
$$
                   \chi_{P}(s)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ist}dP(t)
$$
characterizes the probability measure $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$.